# How to convert unicode to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I know this kind of question has been asked before but I am not able to find solution for my problem

My function is returning me unicode in this format

```
{"set_id": "Rome", "group": "human", "attachments": null, , "object_type": "Prop", "attached": null, "tag_id": "prop", "Double Click": "reference", "files": "/makeup/Data/weapons/rifle", "source": "cupid", "attachment_label": null, "require_attachment": true, "rate": "high", "location": "/set2/ep1/Objects/weapons/machineguns/gun.txt", "attachment_type": null, "icon_path": "/resource/asset_manager/icons/rifle.bmp"}
```

while checking with type it shows it is `<type 'unicode'>`

I tried with `ast.literal_eval(myver)` but no luck
which are other ways to convert it to python dictionary?

Comment: That looks like a [JSON-String](http://json.org/) to me. Have you tried `import json; json.loads(myver)`?

Comment: @Felk This is invalid JSON.

Comment: The example contains this bit: `... null, , "object_type": ...`. That double comma indeed is invalid JSON, but it is unclear if OP meant that to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like JSON. You might want to convert it to a python `dict` using python's inbuilt `json` module:

```
import json    
data = json.loads(myver)
```